# has_many Page gridfield draft stage

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a DataObject `Product` which `$has_many` `ProductPages`.  `MyObject()->getComponents('SomePages')` returns all live pages associated with my `Product` object.

I need to know all pages (Draft and Published) which are attached to this object, because I want to handle un/publishing them from a GridField inline editing (as well as changing other Page properties like URL and Title).

I managed to get all draft `ProductPage`s by doing:

```
$gridfieldList = Versioned::get_by_stage('ProductPage', 'Stage')
->filter(array(
  "ProductID" => $this->ID
));
```

This returns a DataList of Product Pages but with no knowledge of my associated Product context, meaning when I try to click Save, nothing happens.

If I use `$this->getComponents('ProductPages')` to populate the GridField, all changes are saved correctly on form submission, but if I try to un-publish a page, it then gets "removed" from my GridField.

So my question is basically, which approach can I take here to have the Object's associated pages populate my GridField whilst still being aware of their context (ie, having changes being saved successfully)?

Worth noting that I'm running SS 3.1.5 on this site =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew, 3.1.5 is pretty outdated, I just looked up in 3.1.12 and found something useful.

The problem is, that the `Versioned` DataExtension automatically modifies the SQL query to filter the current stage. And any Page can have different statuses and therefor be in different database tables. Fortunately Versioned can check for a DataQuery parameter, so something like this might help you:

```
$this->MyRelation()
    ->setDataQueryParam('Versioned.mode', 'all_versions');
```

See [Versioned::augmentSQL()](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1.10/model/Versioned.php#L188)

Comment: Thanks @wmk, whilst `'all_versions'` was not what I was looking for, `'latest_versions'` did it for me. Cheers.

Comment: @leomeloxp from the code comment: `latest_version has one more step:
Return latest version instances, regardless of whether they are on a particular stage. This provides "show all, including deleted" functonality`